# Pass a php variable from one page to another php page

Tags: php

In my webpage I have a variable called $DOB to validate the date of birth of a person. All I want to do is after validation $dob variable value would be send to a database. I am using my insert query in another page called "submission.php". SO I want to access $DOB variable value to send the data from "submission.php" page.

Comment: I dnt know how to pass one php variable to another page. Need help!

Comment: If you don't rely on databases like MySQL use PHP's Global Variable `$_SESSION`

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to send the validated info into the database? you can store that information in a session variable. If you want to check even after the browser is closed then you can store the information inside a cookie.

Comment: I'm implementing en Employee Management System. So I want to send the data into database after validation. The validation is performed using php in another file. I want to access all the variable in a separate php file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SESSION`

**one_page.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["foo"] = "bar";
```

**the_other_page.php**

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["foo"];
```

Answer (score -1):

If these are different requests, then indeed you need sessions.

But, if by 'page' you mean files and this is one request, then it's simpler. Just 'include' (require) the other  file, and you have access to previously defined variables, like this:

```
file_a.php:

//blah
//blah
$someVar = 42;

require 'file_b.php';

//now, file_b.php:

echo $someVar;//will output 42
```

BTW, it's much better to make a function like 'submit' in the file_b.php and call that function from file_a.php.